# Susy Undefined mixin 'span-columns'

Tags: susy-compass

Keep getting this error.  Undefined mixin 'span-columns'

Here is my gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chunky_png (1.3.1)
compass (0.12.6)
compass-susy-plugin (0.9)
fssm (0.2.10)
sass (3.2.19)
```

My config.rb file:

```
require 'susy'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.


# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "."
sass_dir = "."
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

I used to have everything up and running until I tried to upgrade to Susy 2. I could never get the latest vers of Compass installed w/o errors. So I chose to install the plugin for susy instead of susy itself. I totally screwed up my ruby, rvm etc etc. Just reinstalled the OS. What am i missing here? Do i have to install susy 2 and or update the compass-susy-plugin? If so how do I update the compass-susy-plugin Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Susy syntax error: Undefined mixing 'span-columns'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596028/susy-syntax-error-undefined-mixing-span-columns)

Comment: Possible. However, there is no explanation on how to update that susy plugin. And I have uninstalled all of it and re-installed all of it, even susy itself. I still get these errors. I will try again.

Comment: Ok, after  much investigation, I will either downgrade to Susy 1 or just use susy 2. Susy 2 does not need compass to run. I can always have sass watch and compile. Not bad for a noob. :)

Answer (score 0):

Susy 2 requires SASS 3.3 and compass --pre. Actually, this has been mentioned quite a few times. You will find this information in the docs. You could also use Bundler which will ensure that your gems are correct.

Comment: Thanks. I understood that but did not know how to actually go about getting the lower version of susy after upgraded to susy 2. The compass--pre never installed correctly for me. It always threw errors. I eventually figured it out. It was a pretty 'duh' moment.